# react app creation going to stop after showing "found 1 low severity vulnerability run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

When running the following command in Visual Studio Code to create a react app:

```
create-react-app my-first-react-app
```

It stops progress and shows the following message:

> ```
> found 1 low severity vulnerability
>   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> ```

Till then it only creates node module, `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, and it does not create `app.js`, `public`, `src` dir and files.

So please help me to create a react app.

Below show the steps I followed to create a react app and the resultant log:

> ```
> PS D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app> npm install -g create-react-app     
> C:\Users\Mahendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\Mahendra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
> + create-react-app@3.4.1
> updated 1 package in 60.481s
> PS D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app> create-react-app my-first-react-app 
>
> Creating a new React app in D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
>
> > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
>
> > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app\node_modules\core-js
> > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
>
> > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> + react-scripts@3.4.1
> + react-dom@16.13.1
> + react@16.13.1
> + cra-template@1.0.3
> added 1626 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1630 packages in 1114.609s
>
> 59 packages are looking for funding
>   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 1 low severity vulnerability
>   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> ```

[Sreenshot showing the same error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4DN.jpg)

Comment: It doesn't stop progress - the audit *warnings* are the last thing printed in the install, after that it's finished.

Comment: according to the log, you have no error. your react app should be in folder D:\C_programs\NodeJsApp\my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app  and one more detail - your source code in the sub directory "my-first-react-app\my-first-react-app". i mean you have 2 folders with same name one inside another "my-first-react-app" - code should be in the last one

Comment: the audit warning is not last warning because in the created app directory some directories like src, public , app.js are mot there.<br>  And if it is completed i do not need to press ctrl+C to run other commands

Comment: @Mahendra Are you giving it enough time to complete? Try run it and come back a few minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The issue for me was my anti-malware software that blocked certain packages to download.
Try to deactivate this software and write `create-react-app my-first-react-app` to your console again.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i did as you suggested but still same problem.